# Java edit Serializable edit objects in file

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Serialized object that is stored in an "index.dat" file, 
im reading this serialized file using this code:

```
try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("index.dat");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            Object obj  = null;
            while( (obj = in.readObject()) != null ){
                Word w = (Word) obj;
                System.out.println(w.getWord());
                System.out.println("_____");
            }   
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        }
```

Now is there anyway to edit the retrieved object(in this case its `obj`) and save it in the same position?

Comment: Well... yeah.  Just modify your Word instance, then serialize and write out over that file.

Comment: you mean re-insert it in the file 0.o? wouldnt it be duplicated?

Comment: "write out over"  means overwrite.

Comment: yea but how can i over write? that was the meaning of my question in the first place

Comment: Use a FileOutputStream?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+overwrite+file

Comment: no i dont want to over write the whole file, cant i just "over write" that object? or replace a specified object by another one?

Comment: No you absolutely cannot piece-meal overwrite bits of a serialized object file and expect it to work.  That's why you should read it in, make your changes and reserialize.  If you feel like you need to do this then you need to re-examine your design.

Comment: so i have to read in the "entire" file, then create a new one?

Comment: I recommend that yes.  The whole point of readObject() is you don't need to know how it's stored.  Let's say you figure out the delimiter java is using and then they change it with the next java update?  What you're trying to do is dangerous.

Comment: well ... i could do that in good old Pascal :( .. thanks anyways.

Comment: No you couldn't. You didn't have Serialization in Pascal. You could overwrite fixed-length records in Pascal, or any other language. Serialization doesn't produce fixed-length records.

Comment: yea, i meant the records, you could access any stored record in a file giving the position.